# passing data between Kubeflow pipelines containers

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kubernetes, kubeflow-pipelines, kfp

So I am wondering how can I pass data frame then model between Kubeflow containers which I deployed locally using k8s. Right now I am using v2 sdk and func_to_container_op decorator but I am also interested in how to do it using docker files and creating containers from docker

I found out I should use Input and OutPut function and artifacts but I am not sure how it works in case of passing local files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local file cannot be directly passed between component. You can either serialize it to a string or wrap it into an Artifact. For Artifact, you can first pass the `url` or `path` of the Artifact output to a container argument, which allows you to write content to this file inside the container:

https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/author-a-pipeline/components/#3-custom-container-components

Comment: oh I see I realised like like 2 day's ago. But if I would like to continue it like so I would have to deploy some type of db and take data from db right?

Comment: If you are using Artifact, you don’t need to define a db. Minio is deployed and used by default.